# why was this question closed? (chinese video host)

Tags: support

I made a question asking for recommendations for a chinese video hosting service:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/45266/i-need-a-chinese-video-service-with-player-api

it was closed as non constructive, but I dont see how that is the case.

the FAQ says:
You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

- practical: yes, Chinese market is huge and companies are often required to make changes in their sites to adapt to it. I like to think more than one person is facing with having to build a site for China.
- answerable: yes: "the site chinesehostingvideos.com offers shuch functionality, you can find their documentation at chinesehostingvideos.com/docs" would be enought
- actual problems you face: yes.

Also, it is not a development question so it doesnt fit in stackoverflow

if my question is indeed non constructive. is there a way I can improve it to reopen it?

Answer (score 3):

This question was closed because recommendations are not on-topic for this website. They are subjective and are a polling question. They are better suited for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: could that information be added to the faq?

Comment: @santiagozky It is already there, implicitly. "**What kind of questions should I not ask here?** You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: and yet, as I stated above, my question covered those three conditions.